# Adding matrices to their transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, transpose

If I add a matrix to its transpose matrix, will I get a symmetric matrix? Is $B := A + A^\top$ symmetric?

Comment: Try to do it, what is $B^t$?

Comment: Is $A$ a square matrix?  If not, then the sum isn’t defined.

Comment: oh yeah, it is a square matrix sorry for that :D

Comment: Also isn't $B = 2A = 2A^\top$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes

$$B^T=(A+A^T)^T=A^T+(A^T)^T=A^T+A=A+A^T=B$$

Note $A$ and $A^T$ must have the same dimensions, hence $A$ must be square.

Comment: For this level of question, I should think the second equality should be justified further.  I don't know if @OUR understands why $(C+D)^T=C^T+D^T$.  If he does, then great, it can be left as is.

Comment: Provided $A$ is square.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Otherwise $B$ is not even defined. But it's worth mentioning. Thank you.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right. However, I delay the modification until the OP asks, because then I would need to know how his lesson defines the matrix transpose: if it's based on linear maps and dual spaces, the linearity follows easily, if it's only *"mechanically moving the elements"*, the proof will be different (but not more difficult).

Comment: @JMoravitz I've learned about this rule :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes (when $A$ is a square matrix of dimension $n\times n$).

Let $1\le i,j,k\le n$.

- The diagonal elements of both $A$ and $A^T$ are the same ($\{a_{ii}\}$) so that of $A+A^T$ are $2\times\{a_{ii}\}$.
- Also, a non-diagonal element of $A$ has the form $\{a_{jk}\}$ where $j\neq k$ and that of $A^T$ has the form $\{a_{kj}\}$. So the element of $A+A^T$ on the $j$th row and $k$th column is the same as that on the $k$th row and $j$th column - both are equal to $a_{jk}+a_{kj}=a_{kj}+a_{jk}$.

Combining these two yields the result.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering... one more questions if you mind.. my question got edited, with this symbol:   :=  
what does that mean? does it have the same meaning as "=" ?

Comment: @OUR It means the marix $B$ is **defined** to be $A+A^T$. Some use this symbol to make it clear it's not, for instance, an equation. This notation is not univesal, and you can safely remove the colon if you wish.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)